# How to set multiple counters in LaTeX?

Tags: counters, amsthm

Suppose I defined theorem-like environments in `amsthm`: `problem`, `exercise`, `solution`. I want something like this:

Problem 1.

Solution 1.

Solution 2.

Exercise 1.

Solution 1.

Solution 2.

However, in my document it is like this:

Problem 1.

Solution 1.

Solution 2.

Exercise 1.

Solution 3.

Solution 4.

I made a counter so that the solutions reset each time a new problem begins like this:

```
\counterwithin*{solution}{problem}
```

Can't I add another counter so that they also reset each time a new exercise begins? Like this:

```
\counterwithin*{solution}{problem, exercise}
```

Please help. Thank you!

Comment: Can't you have two different environments for the two solutions? That way you could do something like `\newtheorem{solutionE}{Solution}[exercise}` and `\newtheorem{solutionP}{Solution}[problem]`.

Comment: just use counterwith twice once to say solution is reset by problem and once to say it is reset by exercise

Comment: Thank you so much!